# C# - Concurrent Requests to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, concurrency

I have an application that will likely make more than the available concurrent requests to a database I have hosted on a GoDaddy server.  I'm wondering if when a user makes a request to the database and is denied because of the concurrent request limit what exactly will happen?  Will that request just be tossed like an uncaught exception?  Will it send back an exception that the database is unable to be reached or will it "queue up" and wait its turn?

I've tried doing some research here and either I'm typing in the wrong keywords or I'm just misunderstanding how all this works.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the database has reached max_allowed_connections it will just refuse to connect. in your c# you should try and catch connection where you will trap the exception.
PS: mysql server will close the connection after a certain idle time but its good if you close after your operation is done.

Comment: @krishKM thanks for the reply. I always close the connection when I am finished with it so I keep it open only long enough to do what I need to do.

Is there anything I can do to create a queue of sorts? What I'd like to do is have my app keep doing its thing but query the database when a connection becomes available.

Even just a link to information related to how one would do this would be enough. I don't mind reading.